# How do I match a 10 character sub-string starting with 'H' in a longer string with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, string-parsing

I have the following string:

```
/Users/patelc75/Documents/code/haloror/dialup/H200000787_1313406125/H200000787_1313389058_1.xml
```

In Ruby, how do I extract the first 10 character substring that starts with the letter `H` and contains 9 digits (digits only) after the `H`. In this above example, the substring would be `H200000787`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[String#[]](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/String#%5B%5D-instance_method) method is what you need:

```
str = '/Users/patelc75/Documents/code/haloror/dialup/H200000787_1313406125/H200000787_1313389058_1.xml'

puts str[/H\d{9}/]     #=> H200000787
```

Comment: Ok, I give up. How does that work?  If it had been `str =~ /H\d{9}/`  it would have returned just an integer. What makes it special in the brackets so that you get `$&` out of it?

Comment: @tchrist `String#=~` returns position of the first match (if any) or nil, and populates variable `$&` with content of that match. `String#[]` with regexp just returns match content.

Comment: Yes, but why? The brackets should just want an integer. Why does the match act differently within them, and know to use that string while it's there?

Comment: @tchrist brackets support different types of arguments, look at link in the post.

Answer (score 2):

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "/Users/patelc75/Documents/code/haloror/dialup/H200000787_1313406125/H200000787_1313389058_1.xml"
=> "/Users/patelc75/Documents/code/haloror/dialup/H200000787_1313406125/H200000787_1313389058_1.xml"
irb(main):002:0> s =~ /H\d{9}/
=> 46
irb(main):003:0> $&
=> "H200000787"
```